# Error injecting two dependencies Iconfiguration and IMemoryCache in service from Startup net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, caching, dependency-injection

I'm trying to use IMemoryCache in a service than used Iconfiguration, but actually i dont know the correct way to inject in the constructor.

The service:

```
 public class AuthService: IAuthService
 {
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

    public AuthService(IConfiguration configuration, IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _configuration= configuration;
        _cache = cache;
    }
 }
```

*Inject like singleton way in Startup (**Error: Generate error when consume any controller with that service**):

```
  services.AddMemoryCache();
  services.AddSingleton<AuthService>();
```

*Inject creating class Service in Startup (**Error: needs IMemoryCache on constructor**)

```
services.AddMemoryCache();
services.AddSingleton<IAuthService>(
         new AuthService(Configuration)
);
```

**What is the correct way to inject IMemoryCache into AuthService from Startup class?**

Comment: Perhaps you meant `services.AddSingleton<IAuthService, AuthService>();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`services.AddMemoryCache()` will [register](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/src/MemoryCacheServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L22) an instance as a singleton, meaning that there are no mismatched lifecycles.

In addition, there is no need to manually specify a factory. As Jesse mentioned above, register both your interface and concrete class and the Dependency Injection framework will provide both dependencies to your service:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthService, AuthService>();
```